# References in VBA

Tags: vba, dll, automation

I am trying to do various automation projects using different applications.   In the projects I have done, I have had to set references either to pre-existing "libraries" or, in one case (Avaya CMS) I had to browse from the reference section to an .exe and .dlls.   I thought perhaps, I could just reference dll's and have access to the functions contained in them, but when I tried to link to other dll's I get an error message that a reference cannot be set up for that file.   Does anyone know how I can determine which dll's I can set references to?  Also, in the case of Avaya, there were dozens of dll's, but following an old post, I only needed a few of them.  How would I know which dll's to add?  Is there any guide to the pre-existing libraries in Excel that anyone is aware of?   Any help anybody can provide would be extremely helpful.

Comment: Not all dll's can be added as references in Excel - you have to depend on the documentation for the particular library you want to use to tell you which to add. There is no comprehensive listing of all types which can be added, since they all originate from a large number of different sources.

Comment: Where would I find the documentation?   In the case of Avaya, I  tried reading the user guide but it really only referenced scripting through the CMS application.   Am I looking in the wrong location?

Comment: I can't comment on any of the Avaya documentation.  As for other libraries that really depends a lot on the vendor.

Comment: Thank you for the response.   I appreciate your help.